# Drawing rounded triangle with CSS

Tags: css, drawing

I want to round this triangle:

http://jsfiddle.net/RNsW2/

to be something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this with CSS? I don't want to use images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
div {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Opera */
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Firefox */
    background-color:green;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:-50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
    border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
}
```

and [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K44mE/).

If you want the div with rounded corners to be shown correctly also **in older browsers without CSS3 suppport**, use this:

grab the screen with <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> key, paste it to **Paint** program, shrink the borders and save, open in [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) and Save as (convert it to) *transparent PNG*, then convert it to Base64 image e.g. [here](http://www.base64-image.de/), grab your result and your CSS is done. The result here:

```css
div.image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 62px;
    height: 141px;
    background-image:url('data:image/png;base64,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');
    z-index:-1;
}
```

and [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K44mE/2/)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the CSS transformations:

```
.arrow-right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 26px;
    left: -60px;
    border: 60px solid green;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/n3Ttf/

My fiddle requires a Webkit browser like Safari or Chrome, but you can use different prefixes for other browsers and the filter attribute for IE: http://davidwalsh.name/css-transform-rotate