# Triangle with one rounded corner

Tags: css, svg, css-shapes

I want to make only **one rounded corner for a triangle** but I'm unable to make it.
Here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/shoaibista/9D3Zn/1/):

```css
.arrow-left {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 80px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 80px solid transparent;
  border-right: 80px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-left"></div>
```

I need the corner pointing left to be rounded as shown in this image :

[image: Triangle with a rounded corner]

Comment: To be looked like a semi-circle?

Comment: Easiest way would be to make a transparent png overlay that has a small white curve on the left side that covers the tip of the triangle... You could also use a box with rounded edges rotated 45degrees with everything but the tip covered up with an opaque div.

Comment: similar question only on opposite direction - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913645/drawing-rounded-triangle-with-css

Comment: See this pen http://codepen.io/valentinfarcas/pen/xGrlD

Comment: I would use a SVG nested in an image tag. That would be more semantic for a graphic element than using empty block elements

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I know this is a little hacky, but I don't think there is an easy way to do this with a single class.

All I've done is rotated a box 45 degrees with `border-radius:10px` and then contained it in another div with width set to the desired width of your arrow and `overflow:hidden` so that everything that spills over is invisible.

```css
.arrow-left {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 20px;
  background: black;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.cover {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
  <div class="arrow-left"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: NICE one! I knew you could create arrows with some border hacks, but I didn't knew you could take it further with the border-radius.
Did a quick search on caniuse and browser support seems ok(except ie8, but who cares for an arrow), http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius

Answer (score 15):

You can make a **responsive triangle with one rounded corner** with at least 2 approaches :

### With CSS:

With one `div`and a pseudo element and:

- absolute positioning
- the [padding technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10441480/1811992) to keep the triangle aspect ratio
- [2d transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)
- `overflow:hidden;`
- the [transform technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24808936/1811992) to make the triangle

```css
.arrow-left {  
  position: relative;
  width: 15%;
  padding-bottom:15%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin:100% 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.arrow-left:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right:8px;
  width:100%; height:141%;
  transform-origin:inherit;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-left"></div>
```

*Note that you need to add the vendor prefixes to the transform and transform-origin properties (more info  on [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d))*

### With inline SVG:

This example uses one [path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) element for the triangle with a [bezier curve command](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Bezier_Curves) for the rounded corner (`Q0 5 0.8 4.2` in the `d` attribute):

```css
svg{
  display:block;
  width:10%;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 5 10">
  <path d="M5 0 V10 L0.8 5.8 Q0 5 0.8 4.2z" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this and modify according to your needs.

http://jsfiddle.net/K44mE/947/

```css
#player {
  margin: 32px;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #222;
}

#inner {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: silver;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 20px;
  left: -60px;
  position: relative;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#outer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 165px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 140px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="player">

  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `overflow: hidden;`

```
.corner {
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 4px;
 overflow: hidden;
 top: 0em;
 right: 0em;
 margin: 0em;
 padding: 0em;
 text-align: center;
 border-color: #E8E8E8;
 width: 4em;
 height: 4em;
 z-index: 1;
 -webkit-transition: border-color 0.1s ease;
 transition: border-color 0.1s ease;
 }

.corner:after {
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 right: 0em;
 top: 0em;
 z-index: -1;
 width: 0em;
 height: 0em;
 background-color: transparent !important;
 border-top: 0em solid transparent;
 border-right: 4em solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 4em solid transparent;
 border-left: 0em solid transparent;
 border-right-color: inherit;
 -webkit-transition: border-color 0.1s ease;
 transition: border-color 0.1s ease;
 }
```

Answer (score -3):

to your code to add this

```
border-radius:10px
```