# Drawing curvy triangle in css for menu

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to make a menu with a curvy triangle pointers. I tried but not able to achieve the curvy one.

```
<div>

</div>

div{
    position:relative;
    left:20%;
    height:250px;
    width:150px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    top:10%;
    background:#fff;
}
div:before, div:after{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    left:-20px;
    border:10px solid transparent;
    border-right-color:#fff;
    top:30px;
 }
div:after{
    left:-21px;
    border-right-color:#000;
    z-index:-1
}
```

Refer the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ffneu0cz/)

Also i have attached image above for what i'm actually looking for[image]

I recommend solutions without using SVG

Comment: I think you might be asking too much of css here.  Have you tried using an image instead?

Comment: I can make easily with image @Graham. But any possibilities with css

Comment: It is possible to do with `transform`.

Comment: you can try with this one https://jsfiddle.net/ffneu0cz/3/

Comment: @Harry check my image. I want curvy al the way. Not only at the top of the triangle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing rounded triangle with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913645/drawing-rounded-triangle-with-css)

Comment: Oh ok @SanthoshKumar but then you're restricting your options a lot. Such shapes with outward curves can't be done easily with CSS. SVG would be your best bet.

Answer (score 3):

This might help

- http://dabblet.com/gist/4592062
- [How to make 3-corner-rounded triangle in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14446677/1397351)

```css
/**
 * How to make 3-corner-rounded triangle in CSS (SO)
 * https://stackoverflow.com/q/14446677/1397351
 */
.triangle {
 position: relative;
 background-color: orange;
 text-align: left;
}
.triangle:before,
.triangle:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 background-color: inherit;
}
.triangle,
.triangle:before,
.triangle:after {
 width:  100px;
 height: 100px;
 border-top-right-radius: 30%;
}

.triangle {
 transform: rotate(90deg) skewX(-30deg) scale(1,.866);
}
.triangle:before {
 transform: rotate(-135deg) skewX(-45deg) scale(1.414,.707) translate(0,-50%);
}
.triangle:after {
 transform: rotate(135deg) skewY(-45deg) scale(.707,1.414) translate(50%);
}



/* styles below for demonstration purposes only */
body { padding: 70px; }
.triangle:hover { background: rgba(0,0,255,.5) }
.triangle:hover:before { background: rgba(255,0,0,.5) }
.triangle:hover:after { background: rgba(255,255,0,.5) }
```

```html
<!-- content to be placed inside <body>…</body> -->
<div class='triangle'></div>
```

Comment: Yes, I did it and also did few changes, to rotate it. You can see it in comment.

Answer (score 3):

Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ffneu0cz/4/).

And another [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ffneu0cz/6/)

I have used box with `transform` and `box-shadow` on before and after. Please check my code and if you are getting confusion on any point then let me know. Thank you

**CSS**

```
div{
  position:relative;
  left:20%;
  height:250px;
  width:150px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  top:10%;
  background:#fff;
}
div:before, div:after{
  position:absolute;
  content:'';
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  left:-12px;
  background:#fff;
  top:30px;
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);

    border-radius:5px;
}
div:after{
  left:-13px;
  border-right-color:#000;
  z-index:-1;
  border:1px solid #000;
  top:29px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px 0px #282828;
}
```